# cordova-plugin-media-with-compression is not working with phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I really need this plugin but this plugin is not working with `build.phonegap.com`

I always encounter the following error:

> Error - A plugin in your app does not support the compulsory arm64
>   (64-bit support) architecture.

I need to this to record audio in small size (compressed format) and further I need to pause and resume recording feature.

Please someone help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution for my own question/issue:

Actually I was using `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" />`
in config.xml

And then below I added  `<gap:plugin name="cordova-media-with-compression"  source="npm"  />`

we cannot use both at the same.

I just removed `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" />`

And it started to work fine like charm.

I hope that this will help someone someday.

Comment: it is best if you accept your own answer if you solve your own problem and will not consider accepting any other answers thanks!

Comment: It is saying that I can not accept answer before 2 days.